Troubleshoot negative reading from thermistor sensor when the projector powers on
I'm in the process of fixing Epson EB-E500 projector lamp/temperature error. The projector turns on correctly, it displays the interface and after about 15 seconds the display shuts off and the fans spin faster and either the lamp and temp lights indicate error or just the temp light.
I have narrowed down the problem to something to do with the thermistor sensors. Uplugged from the motherboard, the sensor shows around 12k Ohm reading on the multimeter. Plugged in, the reading is about 2.6k Ohm and as soon as the projector is turned on the reading is negative. View images below to get a beter understanding.


I only want to know what can i do to figure out what is causing the negative reading. What should I test. What reading should I test, etc.
I suspect it must be some kind of interference. But I don't know how to test for that. I have taken the project apart and tried everything I can think of to figure out what the problem is. I'm even thinking of reprogramming the software to completly ignore the temperature (not recommended, I know).
Whatever possible thought that comes to your mind would be appreciated.

You cannot expect to read the resistance with the sensor plugged in, let alone powered. There is some internal circuit that will shunt the resistance when it is plugged in (causing a lower resistance reading), and when powered there will be a voltage that appears across it, which is exactly what is causing your negative reading. That is completely normal and does not suggest any particular issue.
You should try to find a service manual that tells you how to test the sensor, or specifications on the sensor. Even compare it against another known-good sensor.
If there is more than one sensor of the exact same type compare the two with them at roughly the same temperature and they should be roughly the same resistance (within may be 10-20% unless you take precautions to equalize the temperatures).
From what little you've told us, I would look at failed electrolytic capacitors in the power supply (which tend to cause systemic issues that can manifest in various ways) or possibly a failed thermistor. And at mechanical issues (cracked or contaminated circuit boards, loose connectors, that sort of thing, especially if the unit has been abused in some way such as dropped or left outside).

"failed electrolytic capacitors in the power supply" Would it help if I test the voltage output on the connector that plugs into the motherboard. There's a cable with 10 pins coming out from the psu.

I tested the sensor at the intake and the one at the exhuast. The 2 sensor works fine. I'm considering that it might be the psu. Just need to figure out how to test the psu

Capacitors in the power supply should be inspected for leaking or bulging, and tested with an ESR meter.

".. when powered there will be a voltage that appears across it.." What I want to understand is how then will the system detect a fluctuation in temperature.

Well we don't know the circuit without a schematic. The simplest arrangement is a voltage divider to some unknown voltage (maybe 5 or 3.3v) with an unknown resistor. Then a circuit (maybe an MCU) can read the voltage, which will be Vunknown*(Rtherm/(Rtherm + Runknown)) or  Vunknown*(Runknown/(Rtherm + Runknown)), depending on which way the divider is connected. Or it could be something else circuit-wise, but in any case, to measure the temperature, current will  go through the thermistor and a voltage will appear across it, either of which (voltage or current) can be measured.

Your multimeter does something similar, which is why you get nonsensical readings when the unit is powered. You get sensible, but useless, readings when it's not powered because other stuff is in parallel.

I'm busy with a ground continuity check that I'm following in the service manuall. The reading between the pc terminal and ac inlet of the projector. The resistance should be 0.5 ohm or less but I'm getting 58 ohms. what does this mean? what could be the issue

Can't really come up with a useful guess from that info.

I'm busy fixing my projector. It gives lamp error but I don't believe the lamp is broken. I've done the following test: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1963583/Epson-Eb-E01.html?page=144#manual and I get a resistance value of 58. The meter's dail is set to 2000 ohms. Isn't this an indication of what could possiblly be the cause of the issue I'm facing? Also, what would you do to solve this problem

Spehro, on the power supply board the voltage reads +17 volts but when i test with a multimeter I get 12 volts. Is this normal? Also I tested restistance on the capacitors and the blue ceramic ones doesn't have resistance. Is that the cause of outputing only 12 volts

I need your expertise for a moment and I don't want to create another question right now
